# Classifying groups of order 8 (semidirect products)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, semidirect-product

I am trying to classify groups of order 8 (we call it $G$). I understand there are similar questions on this website, but none of them is compatible to what I am expecting.

Basically, I understand that there is a subgroup of order $4$, by the proposition that if $p^{\alpha} \mid |G|$, then $G$ must have a group of order $p^{\alpha}$. Call this subgroup of order $4$ $N$. As $[G : N] = 2$, we also know that $N \triangleleft G$.

Let $K \cong G/N$. We know a short exact sequence $1 \rightarrow N \rightarrow G \rightarrow K \rightarrow 1$.

I am asked to show if this sequence does not split, then we have either the quaternion group or an abelian one.  Here is what I tried. If this sequence does not split, so $K \cap N = \{e, h\}$, s.h. $h$ is an element of order $2$. I believe if I can show that $N$ cannot be the Klein-4 group, but $\mathbb{Z}/4$, I can prove that $G \cong Q_8$ or $G \cong \mathbb{Z}/8$. Not sure which step I am missing here.

The second part is to show that if the sequence splits, we can construct all the other three groups of order $8$, using semidirect products, considering different automorphisms.

The second part is more clear to me, but I am not sure how to proceed in the first part.
Could anyone help me?

Comment: What is $K\cap N$? $K$ is not a subset of $G$. And are you sure you want to say that "$h$ is an element of order $1$", cause the only such element is the identity.

Comment: sorry, $K \cong G/N$, $h$ is an element of order 2. Gonna fix the question.

Comment: The subgroup $K$ is not well-defined. There may be multiple subgroups that accomplish this, or none. You really shouldn't do that in the "non-split" case. Instead, what you know is that if $g\in G$ maps to a generator of $G/N$, then $\langle g\rangle\cap N\neq\{e\}$ (in particular, $g$ is not of order $2$).

Comment: I am not sure if I got it @ArturoMagidin. I wonder if you could provide a more complete answer below.

Comment: I wasn't answering. I was telling you that talking about $K$ as a specific subgroup of $G$ is not valid. If you want to talk about a subgroup, then since $G/N$ is cyclic of order $2$, if you pick any element of $G$ whose image generates that quotient, then it must be of order a multple of $2$. If the extension does not split, then no such element can have order exactly $2$. That is all I said.

Comment: $N$ can be the Klein $4$ group. If your group is the abelian group $C_2\times C_4$, and you pick the Klein $4$ subgroup, then the resulting sequence does not split, since $N$ contains all elements of order $2$. So at best you'll have to consider the case where $N$ is the Klein 4 group separately.